# Matplotlib density plot in polar coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, density-plot

I have an array saved as a txt file that has entries corresponding to the value of a distribution in polar coordinates. So it looks like this:

```
  f(r1,theta1) f(r1, theta2) ..... f(r1, theta_max)
  f(r2,theta1) f(r2, theta2) .....        .
        .                                 .
        .                                 .
        .                                 .
  f(r_max,theta1) .................f(r_max, theta_max)
```

I want to do a density plot of f (the higher f is, the more red I want the color to be). Is there a way to do this with matplotlib? Explicit code would be helpful, as I am majorly new to this.

Comment: I don't think you actually need a density plot -- you have one entry f(r,t) for each polar grid coordinate, yes? But the value of f varies from point to point? You just need to heat-map that array on a polar plot, then.

Comment: @cphlewis, right, that's what I meant. I misspoke because (not that it matters) f is a density function.

Comment: Also, I found a good resource for this -- http://blog.rtwilson.com/producing-polar-contour-plots-with-matplotlib/

Answer (score 8):

In this example, `a` is you theta1...thetan, `b` is your r1...rn, `c` is your f(a, b):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

#fake data:
a = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
b = np.linspace(0,1,50)
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)
c = np.random.random(A.shape)

#actual plotting
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ctf = ax.contourf(a, b, c, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.colorbar(ctf)
```

[image]

Essentially a filled contour plot in polar axis.
You can specify alternative colormap with the `cmap=...`. `cm.jet` goes from blue to red, with red being the largest value.